# How do i stop Phonegap Android app crashing when typing &

Tags: android, html, cordova

For some strange reason when entering text into a `<input type="text">` input in my app pressing the `&` key causes the application to crash.

Is anyone aware of some way to fix this or of why this is happening?

Comment: Are you doing any sort of `onchange` processing on the input? If you are, it could it be something in there not liking the & symbol.

Comment: No, no `onchange` handler in my javascript. Phonegap may implement some kind of handler though